# $G$ a group of order 36, $P$ is the only Sylow 3-subgroup, which is normal, prove the existence of a homomorphism $\phi:G\rightarrow S_4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Specifically the question I was asked was to prove that there was either a normal subgroup of $G$ of index 4 or that there was a non-trivial homomorphism $\phi:G\rightarrow S_4$, i.e., such that $\phi(g)\neq 1$ for some $g$. As $n_3=|G:N_G(P)|$ for any Sylow p-subgroup and $n_3=1,4$, if $n_3=4$ I'm done so I set $n_3=1$ and proved the information I have in the title but I can't get any further.

Comment: There's always at least one homomorphism between two groups.

Comment: Sorry, I meant non-trivial homomorphism, editing now.

Comment: This is a crazy question because any group of order $36$ has a nontrivial homomorphism to $S_4$ defined by the multiplication action on the $4$ cosets of a Sylow $3$-subgroup.

Answer (score 1):

If $P$ is the unique Sylow subgroup it must be normal (a conjugate of $P$ would be a different Sylow subgroup).

Comment: So then this implies that there is always a normal subgroup of index 4? If so there is no need for the homomorphism clause.

Comment: No it is not true that there is always a normal subgroup of index $4$. But it is true that there is always a nontrivial homomorphism to $S_4$.

Comment: @PepeSilvia one or the other is true.